# Rules, URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite two URLs.

- `/Inicio.aspx` to `/Home`
- and `/Usuario/Solicitud.aspx` to `/Usuario/Solicitudes`

with the module rewrite of IIS.

I made my rules:

[image: Edit inbound rule #1]

---

[image: Edit inbound rule #1]

and put the code in the web.config

```
<rule name="Clean url" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Inicio$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Home" />
  </rule>

  <rule name="Clean solicitud" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Usuario/Solicitud$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Usuario/Solicitudes" />
  </rule>
```

But it's not working.

I even put this in `Global.asax`:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
{

    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("", "{Home}", "~/Inicio.aspx");
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("", "Usuario/{Solicitud}", "~/Usuario/Solicitud.aspx");
}
```

I've been trying to solve this for days.

Comment: "`/Inicio.aspx` to `/Home`" - Shouldn't this be the other way round? But your `<match>` directives (although look the wrong way round - as mentioned) are also missing the file extension `.aspx` as stated in your example?

Comment: No, you have to put a $ instead of the file extension, because if you don't, causes an error. So it's necesary. I really tried everything, but i don't know what is the problem

Comment: Is the file extension part of the URL you are trying to match?

Comment: Yes, is part of it, but i even tried it, but i don't know what is wrong

Comment: I don't believe the part of "because if you don't, causes an error". Using a wrong regular expression above won't give you **anything**. If the correct regular expression gives you another error, edit your question to reveal what exactly is that error.

Comment: Sorry, i noticed what causes the Error 404.0 when i write my rule like this: ^Inicio.aspx send a error, but just in that case. writing in any other way the aplication runs but doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

> i noticed what causes the Error 404.0 when i write my rule like this: ^Inicio.aspx send a error, but just in that case. writing in any other way the aplication runs but doesn't do anything

That 404 suggests that it is "working", but that `/Home` is not a valid URL-path. (Does `/Home` route OK when you request it directly? I assume not.) A 404 response is just that; an HTTP response, it's not strictly an "error" in this context, as you seemed to imply. Changing the regex to `^Inicio$` avoids the 404 response, but like you say, it "doesn't do anything" - because it will never match - it literally does not do anything.

This goes back to my original comment... shouldn't this be the other way round? eg. Linking to `/Home` (the "Clean url" URL) and rewriting from `/Home` to `/Inicio.aspx` (the underlying filesystem path)?

In which case, your rules become something like:

```
<rule name="Clean url" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^/Home$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/Inicio.aspx" />
</rule>
```